# Inflate Bottom Navigation View menu programmatically

Tags: android, menuitem, bottomnavigationview, inflate-exception

Bottom Navigation View has been added to version 25 of the Design Support Library. Tried  and it's much easier to use now.

But I am facing problem implementing it as per my app requirements.
I want to inflate menu resource dynamically and change menu items/titles of the Bottom Navigation view programmatically.

> inflateMenu(int menuResource) — Inflate a menu for the bottom navigation view using a menu resource identifier.

According to docs:

> inflateMenu: void inflateMenu (int resId)
>   Inflate a menu resource into this navigation view.
>   **Existing items in the menu will not be modified or removed.**
>   Parameters
>   resId   int: ID of a menu resource to inflate

Trying to use this *inflateMenu(int resID)* method programmatically with navigation view throws exception "**Resource not found**"

```
bottomNavigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.bottom_navigation_menu);
```

Is it possible to achieve it without any third party libraries?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation" />

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:itemBackground="@color/theme_action_bar_bg"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/white" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Menu Resource:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_bar_item_dashboard"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_nav_bar_dashboard_24px"
        android:title="@string/nav_bar_item_dashboard"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_bar_item_people"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_nav_bar_people_24px"
        android:title="@string/nav_bar_item_people"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_bar_item_classroom"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_nav_bar_classroom_24px"
        android:title="@string/nav_bar_item_classrooms"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_bar_item_manage"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_nav_bar_manage_24px"
        android:title="@string/nav_bar_item_manage"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_bar_item_more"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_nav_bar_more_24px"
        android:title="@string/nav_bar_item_more"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

Inflating Programmatically in menuresource for Bottom Navigation view inside Activity:

```
navBar = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    navBar.inflateMenu(R.menu.bottom_navigation_view);
```

Comment: post your code and layout

Answer (score 51):

```
navigationView.getMenu().clear(); //clear old inflated items.
navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.new_navigation_drawer_items);
```

from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52864098/how-to-change-a-menu-of-a-navigationview-programmatically)

Comment: It works like a charm! No space issue with this. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks alot! Saved me the trouble of using multiple BottomNavigationViews, which would cause other headaches.

Answer (score 34):

```
BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);

//Add MenuItem with icon to Menu
navigation.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 1, Menu.NONE, "Home").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_home_black_24dp);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: We can clear menu before adding new items by using navigation.getMenu().clear();

Comment: If I want to provide a custom view to be the menu item, how can I do that?