# How to change a Menu of a NavigationView programmatically?

Tags: android, kotlin, attributes

Hello I'm wondering how can I change a Menu ID from a NavigationView, in this case it is triggered when the user clicks on a RadioButton. I have that part already but I just need to know how to change the Menu, so in the menu it will display different options when RadioButton is clicked.

```
private var radioAdm:RadioButton? = null
private var radioAtle:RadioButton? = null
private var atletanav:BottomNavigationView? = null
private var menuopt = "@menu/admin_menu"

override fun onCheckedChanged(buttonView: CompoundButton?, isChecked: Boolean) {
     // Here is where I need to put that code
    }
```

I've tried this already but no success:

```
atleta_navbar.set(menu){menu=menuopt}
atleta_navbar.setTag(menuopt)
```

So in the NavigationView it will go from this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In java you could try this to re-inflate NavigationView at runtime.

```
navigationView.getMenu().clear(); //clear old inflated items.
navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.new_navigation_drawer_items);
```

I don't know kotlin,but the thought is same.

Answer (score 0):

this code work for me as explain by navylover answer 
1- make sure you have different menu in my case i have   `R.menu.navigation` and `R.menu.navigation_normal`

```
  private fun User() {
                // clear previous menu
                binding.navi.menu.clear()

               // add new menu item
                binding.navi.inflateMenu(R.menu.navigation)

              //add listener for new bottom naviagtion 

       binding.navi.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener)

                 // when using Navigation component
                //set up bottom navigation bar with navigation graph 
                NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.navi, navController)
            }
```